# AutoHotKey : Get mdi window

Tags: autohotkey

While automating an process in a MDI application, I try to use AutoHotKey.

On a given time, a new mdi child window popups in the MDI application, and I would like to "wait" my autohotkey script until this is opened.

So I was heading for a loop that checks if the control (mdi child) exists.

Using ControlGet, I can't seem to get the mdi child.

This is the child which I would like to know if exists or not.

AutoSpy:

> ( Now Under Mouse Cursor )
>
> ClassNN: FNWND31101
>   Text: Phrase Extraction

[image]

Perhaps I am not using the correct AutoHotKey function to find this?

Script

```
WinWait, FNWND31101,, 10
if ErrorLevel
{
  MsgBox, WinWait timed out.
  return
} else 
{
  MsgBox, Found control  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using winwait like this:

```
winwait, FNWND3110
```

The window has ID: FNWND3110 and the object under the mouse has ID: FNWND31101

Have a look at these URL's:

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/85114-detecting-new-child-window/

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/8398-how-to-winwait-a-mdi-child-window/

And the last argument of MouseGetPos:
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseGetPos.htm

Otherwise, ask at the AHK forum: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/

Comment: Updated my original posting with the script. It does not find the mdi child. Using a MacroRecorder I don't see any WinActivate when I click the mdi child.

Comment: Just edited my answer. WinWait should wait until FNWND3110 has opened, then continue with the script. If you want to control a specific object, use the longer code (this is unusual, often the objects are named button1 or edit1)

Comment: FNWND3110 is actually the MDI container, which is open. The mdi child is the object under the mouse. I've added a new picture which shows it.